# Mysql restore from file

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have Database table saved in a txt file with the format of the following

```
id | name | score | reward | result | note
id | name | score | reward | result | note
id | name | score | reward | result | note
```

I would like to put these database to the mysql database table. Can it be done by using PHP?

what about if the format is

```
|id | name | score | reward | result | note|
|id | name | score | reward | result | note|
|id | name | score | reward | result | note|
```

Comment: yes its quite possible, google `open text file php`. you can start from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you:

```
 $file  = file('file.txt');

foreach ($file as $line) 
{ 
  $column = explode("|", $line);

$a = $column[0];
$b = $column[1];
$c = $column[2];
$d = $column[3];
$e = $column[4];
$f = $column[5];
$query = "INSERT INTO table (a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES ('$a','$b','$c','$d','$e','$f');
mysqli_query($sql,$query);
}
```

You'll want to use prepared statements instead, and you need to alter the insert  depending on your db connection... Of course you need to change table and table columns to your needs

Comment: I think in the second case you'll need to change $a = $column[1]; and so on. You can try it out by just echoing $column[1] and so on instead of inserting directly